# Why do I get a different offsetHeight value within ngOnChanges?

Tags: css, angular

Example plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YLLslImGOpS8u6zx

In the plunker, I display the height and width of a div from the parent component using `ViewChild`.

I pass the div from the parent component to the child component as an Input HTMLElement, and in the child component, I again read the `currentValue` of this input. If you open the browser console, I logged the `SimpleChanges` object. If you look at the `currentValue.offsetHeight`, the height is the expected value (i.e. the value matches what the parent component is displaying)

However, the child component is displaying a different value from the expected.

Whats even stranger is if you edit the child component template to something like:

```
<div>
    <p>Child: {{ display }}</p>
</div>
```

Simply adding some additional content in the div, the child component now displays the expected value (i.e. the value matches what the parent component is displaying, and it matches the value in SimpleChanges)

To put it simply, why does this difference occur?

In my code-base, I'm experiencing an issue using `offsetHeight` where the value within SimpleChanges is accurate, but the value I try to store on an instance variable and use within the component is inaccurate. This plunker probably does not emulate exactly the issue I face in my code-base but maybe understanding the cause/effects of what I described above might help me figure out the problem I face in my code-base.

Thanks!

Comment: By the time you're printing `height` Angular hasn't rendered the DOM yet

Comment: @yurzui yea in the `ngAfterViewInit` the value is there. But, I still don't quite understand why the `SimpleChanges` logged to stdout displays the correct values even though the stdout occurs before the ui render. Also, I don't understand why adding additional elements or characters in the child component template changes the `offsetHeight` value to the expected value (or really just another value)

Comment: In console you have a reference to HTMLDivElement object. When you expand it and look at `currentValue.offsetHeight` it shows you the updated(mutated) value at that time. This is how console works in browser. If you want to see the real value at specific time then use primitive value for that

Comment: @yurzui I see, thank you! I think to answer my question about additional elements/characters in the child component, the template render process must be different. Only having content of template expressions or variables vs using some interpolation or having some raw content in the template. Thanks again!